# How to share partition to be accessed from IIS and store website media files inside it

Tags: iis

I have a website that deployed on local machine on site and not accessed from Internet
the website use large media files [audio/video], and the files are found on the same server but on other partition

I need to show these files in the browser but it can not be done until I add files inside intpub of IIS

is there a way to add the other partitions as shared to IIS and be able to access files from them

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual directory in IIS under the application root, that points to the location where your files are stored. That will allow you to use URLs to access the files therein, from the relative path of the virtual directory within your application. You will need to grant permissions on the directory that allow the application pool user to read the directory.

for a local directory, check these instructions:
https://computingforgeeks.com/configure-virtual-directory-on-windows-iis-server/

and you can even do it for a remote path:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/create-virtual-directory-folder-remote-computer